# Class 'List<DocumentSnapshot>' has no instance getter 'documents'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I am trying to achieve a functionality where the app displays all the users' details in a grid view except the current user's. I have been trying to assign `snapshots` to `_stream` and then apply the `_stream` value in `StreamBuilder()`. But it throws an error instead.

```
Database _database = Database();
Stream _stream;
String currentUserId;

@override
void initState() {
    getCurrentUserId(); //currentUserId gets its value here
    getAllUsers();
    super.initState();
}

getAllUsers() async {


 Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = await _database.getAllUsers();
    
 _stream = snapshots.map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.documents.where((documentSnapshot)
          => documentSnapshot.data["userId"] != currentUserId
  ).toList())
}

//..

StreamBuilder(
stream: _stream,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
 if (snapshot.data != null)
 //..
 
}
//..
)
```

NEW: if I add `as QuerySnapshot`, the `snapshot` in the `StreamBuilder` will be null instead of throwing an exception.

```
// NEW
     _stream = snapshots.map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.documents.where((documentSnapshot)
     => documentSnapshot.data["userId"] != currentUserId
     ).toList() as QuerySnapshot);
```

Database class

```
getAllUsers() async {
    return await _firestore.collection("users").snapshots();
}
```

Exception

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<dynamic, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>>#6e31f):
Class 'List<DocumentSnapshot>' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: documents

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<dynamic> file:///Users/suriantosurianto/AndroidStudioProjects/apui/lib/fragments/home_fragment.dart:66:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _HomeFragmentState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:apui/fragments/home_fragment.dart:80:42)
#2      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:509:81)
#3      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:127:48)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `querySnapshot` is a `List<QuerySnapshot>`, not a `QuerySnapshot`.  So, you have to treat it like a list.

Comment: can you elaborate it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

We do not know which line is this error pointing, however if I understand correctly the reason might be type of `StreamBuilder` property `stream` that should be of `Stream` class ([reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder/stream.html)).

Seems `_stream` is a `list` created from `stream` using `toList` method ([reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/toList.html)). I would try to remove this `toList` method, and see what will happen.

I hope it will help!

Comment: `_stream` is not a list, according to `_stream.runtimeType`, it is a `_MapStream<QuerySnapshot, dynamic>` regardless the `toList()` method

Answer (score 0):

```
// NEW
     _stream = snapshots.map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.documents.where((documentSnapshot)
     => documentSnapshot.data["userId"] != currentUserId
     ).toList() as QuerySnapshot);
```

here the `querySnapshot` is a `List<DocumentSnapshot>`!!!

you are probably have to use `querySnapshot.where()`

Comment: it did not work. And how come querySnapshot is a List<DocumentSnapshot>??

Answer (score 0):

As others point out, querySnapshot is a `List<DocumentSnapshot>` and not `DocumentSnapshot`, so you can't use the getter `.documents`(that getter is for `DocumentSnapshot` only, not for a `List`), This is becasue is retrieving the `DocumentSnapshot` of every user except the current user (a `DocumentSnapshot` for each user, so a `List<DocumentSnapshot>`).

If you want to return a Stream of type of `List<DocumentSnapshot>` then

```
_stream = snapshots
    .map<List<DocumentSnapshot>>((querySnapshot) => 
       querySnapshot.where((documentSnapshot) => 
          documentSnapshot.data["userId"] != currentUserId)
 );
```